# 画像の画素値をあげようとしたら一部が上手く変換されない

Tags: python, 画像

#### 問題点

あるRGB画像を読み込み、RGBの値(輝度値)を全て50あげて保存するプログラムを作成しているのですが、
できあがった画像は一部のピクセルにおいて[0,0,0]になってしまい、結果的に2枚目の画像のような
虫食いになってしまいます。

各ピクセルのRGB値を出力してみるとやはり以下のとおりいくつかのピクセルのRGB値が[0,0,0]になっていました。どうすれば解決できるでしょうか。

#### 環境

Python 3.8.5
Windows 10

#### 結果

**変換前:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**変換後:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 出力結果(一部)

```
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
[50 50 50]
```

#### ソースコード

```
def main():

    width = 416
    height = 416
    num = int(1)
    os.chdir("d:\\study_data\\get_image\\photo\\thermal_face-PascalVOC-export\\JPEGImages")

    while True:

        filename = 'img%20('+format(num)+').jpg'
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            image = cv2.imread(filename)
        else:
            print("\nEnd")
            break

        for y in range(0,height):
            for x in range(0,width):

                image[y,x,0] = image[y,x,0] + 50
                if image[y,x,0] > 255:
                    image[y,x,0] = 255

                image[y,x,1] = image[y,x,1] + 50
                if image[y,x,1] > 255:
                    image[y,x,1] = 255

                image[y,x,2] = image[y,x,2] + 50
                if image[y,x,2] > 255:
                    image[y,x,2] = 255

                #print(image[x,y])

        cv2.imwrite('d:/study_data/get_image/photo/thermal_face-PascalVOC-export/Copy/img%20('+format(num)+').jpg', image)

        num += 1
        print("\rNo. %d" %num, end='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.imread`で読み込まれた画像データは、8bit幅符号なし整数型(`uint8`)として保持されています。実際に、下記コードで確認してみてください。

```
print(image.dtype)  # uint8
```

このデータに対して加算を行うと、結果が値`255`を超える場合には`256`で割った余りとなってしまいます。例：`230 + 50`は`280`ではなく`24`になる。

簡単に解決するなら、中間計算をより広いbit幅を持つ整数型（`uint16`）で行えば解決します。

```
image = image.astype('uint16')
# image[x,y,c]の計算...
```

---

質問趣旨からは少し外れますが、Python＋OpenCV＋Numpyによる画像処理では、ピクセル単位処理は非常に重い（＝速度が遅い）処理です。なるべくNumpy関数を利用した方がよいです。

2次元ループ`x`,`y`×ピクセル単位計算の代わりに、下記のように記述すると同じ処理を高効率に実現できます。

```
image = image.astype('int16')
image = np.clip(image + 50, 0, 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

yohjp さんの回答により無事問題を解決できました、ありがとうございます。

追加情報として、今回の場合は全ての輝度値を +50 にするということで、取りうる値の範囲は 50 ~ 305 となるため uint16 型を用いました。

逆に全ての輝度値を -50 にする場合、その範囲は -50 ~ 205 となり、負の値が範囲に入ってきます。

この場合は uint16 型だと正の値にしか対応していないので、int16 型に変更すれば負の値にも対応できます。

自分への戒めとして残しておきますね。